# Google Map API Javascript v3- How to highlight specific streets/segments of streets within a polygon/rectangle area?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on Google Map API v3, there are many useful features/examples. But I'm still looking for a way to highlight all streets, and only streets with different color within a polygon/rectangle.

Here's what I drew on the map:

[image]

And here's what I would like to show

[image]

I've tried many but can't find a solution.

The only way (and the worst way) I can think of so far is to store all street data, find all the points of the streets within the rectangle/polygon, and draw the polylines connecting them, but that means we need to store a massive amount of data.

I've also thought of Direction Service, but it seems to not be applicable for all cases (for example, very big rectangle).

Comment: It's like I want to change map style but only in a limited area (like rectangle) instead of the full map.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this would be to create two different sets of maps: one with "normal" style and one with "inverse style".  When someone draws a rectangle on top of the "normal" map, then cut out the corresponding piece from the inverse map and paste it over the normal map.

No, this is not easy.  It's not an easy problem.

You can probably use Open Street Map tiles for this if you get the styling right.  See
   http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first one after 5 days of waiting :) I'm still reading your OSM link. But if I use OSM tiles, I can't use Google Map to display them anymore ,right? Do you have any examples for this?

Comment: I just took a (VERY) quick look at the Terms of Use; I don't *think* you are *required* to use the Google map tiles.  You'd just need to define a new map layer.  On the other hand, if you don't need to use the Google Map API, then you can use one of other the slippy map frameworks.  leaflet is what I personally would use in that case.